# Species diversity in cheese and yoghurt?

Tags: genetics, microbiology, virology, yeast

There have been studies on the number of species on humans and in various other environments. I was wondering how many species including: viruses, bacteria, yeasts, and fungi inhabit ordinary farm yoghurt, supermarket yoghurt, and cheeses like parmesan, edam, and blue.

I can find some studies, but not an actual count of species diversity in living dairy products.

Comment: Does the work you found include that by Rachel Dutton (http://www.theduttonlab.com/publications-1/2017/6/14/publications)?  It would be helpful if you could summarize what you have already found.

Comment: Nice find, I didn't see that. http://www.asmscience.org/content/book/10.1128/9781555818593.chap12 sais that there are relatively few species in cheeses. And this study suggests that there are 5-7 main bacteria in the ecosystems, although I didnt find a specific reference on the total diversity. https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4222527/figure/F3/

Comment: Great — I hope you'll post an answer your own question once you feel like you've digested the available literature!

Comment: We did some work on mozzarella cheese: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/30621867.
However, we only studied bacteria. The group of Danilo Ercolini is leading a lot of work in metagenomics of several kinds of cheese (I mostly took inspiration from their work). You can look there for some reference.